# Max and Min on a varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where the data comes in different every month. Last month the data came in like the below:

```
Type          Period
---------------------------
R12           202007-202106
R12           202107-202207
YTD           202101-202106
YTD           202201-202206
```

This month the data looks like the below:

```
Type          Period
---------------------------
R12           202008-202107
R12           202108-202208
YTD           202101-202107
YTD           202201-202208
```

I have been trying to write my SQL code so I don't have to alter my alias in Tableau for the header of the report every month to Prior Period and Current Period. This way I can automate the report and let Tableau refresh the SQL code for me. I am not able to automate because the Period changes every month and that Period ends up as the header in the Tableau report and I have to change it to either Prior Period or Current Period using an alias. Below is the code I tried to write to accomplish this but the results are not what I want. Period is a varchar.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    period, type, 
    CASE 
        WHEN type = 'R12' AND period = MIN(period) 
            THEN 'Prior Period'
        WHEN type = 'R12' AND period = MAX(period) 
            THEN 'Current Period' 
        WHEN type = 'YTD' AND period = MIN(period) 
            THEN 'Prior Period'
        WHEN type = 'YTD' AND period = MAX(period) 
            THEN 'Current Period' 
    END AS [Prior Current]
FROM 
    [Ops411_PMM].[dbo].[vw_macrotrendsaggregatedclaims] WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE
    lob = 'commercial' 
    AND segmentproduct IN ('Indiv ACA', 'Indiv Legacy', 'Large Group FI-NR', 'Small Grp ACA', 'Small Grp Legacy') 
    AND servicetype = 'IP' 
    AND paidthrough IN (SELECT MAX(paidthrough)  
                        FROM [Ops411_PMM].[dbo].[vw_macrotrendsaggregatedclaims] WITH (NOLOCK))
GROUP BY
    lob, segmentproduct, [state], paidthrough, [period], [type], 
    servicetype, servicedetail, inoutcode, networkname,
    segmentproduct,  networkid, membermonth, covid_ind, hospitalsystem
```

The output of this is:

```
period               type   Prior Current
------------------------------------------
202008 - 202107      R12    Prior Period
202101 - 202107      YTD    Prior Period
202108 - 202208      R12    Prior Period
202201 - 202208      YTD    Prior Period
```

This is the output I need to get:

```
period               type   Prior Current
------------------------------------------
202008 - 202107      R12    Prior Period
202101 - 202107      YTD    Prior Period
202108 - 202208      R12    Current Period
202201 - 202208      YTD    Current Period
```

Comment: What is the output that you want? perhaps show the data from the previous month as well to illustrate the problem. right now its hard to see what is wrong

Comment: Is the last data set what you currently have or what you need? You need to show us what your expected results are. Also include your current full query please,

Comment: I edited to show the code. There is more in the select statement that works with that group by but for my purposes just included the case statement. I also put what I need. Again the Periods change every month.

Comment: Why are you comparing `type` in your case expression when the only factor affecting the outcome is the `period`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using a window query to calculate the MAX period for a partitioned group that is different to the group logic in your original query. I've used a CTE to format the query and isolate the logical steps.

```
WITH PeriodData as (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        period, type
    FROM 
        [Ops411_PMM].[dbo].[vw_macrotrendsaggregatedclaims] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE
        lob = 'commercial' 
        AND segmentproduct IN ('Indiv ACA', 'Indiv Legacy', 'Large Group FI-NR', 'Small Grp ACA', 'Small Grp Legacy') 
        AND servicetype = 'IP' 
        AND paidthrough IN (SELECT MAX(paidthrough)  
                            FROM [Ops411_PMM].[dbo].[vw_macrotrendsaggregatedclaims] WITH (NOLOCK))
    GROUP BY
        lob, segmentproduct, [state], paidthrough, [period], [type], 
        servicetype, servicedetail, inoutcode, networkname,
        segmentproduct,  networkid, membermonth, covid_ind, hospitalsystem
),
PeriodDataProcessed as (
    SELECT period, type, MAX(Period) OVER (PARTITION BY type) as MaxPeriod      
    FROM PeriodData
)
SELECT 
    period, type
    CASE 
        WHEN period = MaxPeriod
            THEN 'Current Period' 
        ELSE 'Prior Period'
    END AS [Prior Current]
FROM PeriodDataProcessed
```

The two CTEs could be combined, but I personally feel the intent is clearer by separating the elements like this. A single CTE looks like this:

```
WITH PeriodData as (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        period, type, MAX(Period) OVER (PARTITION BY type) as MaxPeriod
    FROM 
        [Ops411_PMM].[dbo].[vw_macrotrendsaggregatedclaims] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE
        lob = 'commercial' 
        AND segmentproduct IN ('Indiv ACA', 'Indiv Legacy', 'Large Group FI-NR', 'Small Grp ACA', 'Small Grp Legacy') 
        AND servicetype = 'IP' 
        AND paidthrough IN (SELECT MAX(paidthrough)  
                            FROM [Ops411_PMM].[dbo].[vw_macrotrendsaggregatedclaims] WITH (NOLOCK))
    GROUP BY
        lob, segmentproduct, [state], paidthrough, [period], [type], 
        servicetype, servicedetail, inoutcode, networkname,
        segmentproduct,  networkid, membermonth, covid_ind, hospitalsystem
)
SELECT 
    period, type
    CASE 
        WHEN period = MaxPeriod
            THEN 'Current Period' 
        ELSE 'Prior Period'
    END AS [Prior Current]
FROM PeriodData
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out later this afternoon when my meeting is done. :)